# Which different visualizations to make for time series analysis?

Tags: time-series, visualization, data-analysis

I hope you're doing great. I have recently started working on a time series project and I have just finished preparing my data and calculating trends (daily, weekly, yearly) and I wonder what are the different plots I should make using the the absolute values of my variables and the calculated trends?

Also, I'm seeking anyone to tell me what are the best practices to work on time series and what are the details I should pay attention to!

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to time series forecasting. I used simple lineplot to visualize the time series data. Some of the models used for time series are :

1. ARIMA
2. SARIMA
3. prophet
4. LSTM (deep neural networks)
5. LBATS
   You can refer to this [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting/) to know what things you should consider while building a time series model

Comment: This answer would be better if you could provide useful links to definitions of each of the acronyms.